# compile-time conversions of floating point constants

Tags: c++, c++11

This question refers to my previous question: [float conversions in templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584191/float-conversions-in-templates)

I would like to prevent a run-time conversion of floating-point constants. The prevailing view taken in my previous question was, that, say, a `float(.5)` conversion is allowed to take place at run-time. But how about:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
constexpr A convert(B const a)
{
  return a;
}
```

An assert to guarantee the compile-time evaluation of a `constexpr` function is discussed here:
[When does a constexpr function get evaluated at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248235/when-does-a-constexpr-function-get-evaluated-at-compile-time)

Is a `constexpr` + `assert` combination the only guaranteed way to accomplish such conversions at compile-time?

SOLUTION:

After a lot of head-scratching, I've come to the conclusion, that the `convert` function I've provided is unnecessary. The best I could come with was:

```
#define CONVERT(T, V) static constexpr T const T##_##V(V)

int main()
{
  CONVERT(float, 1);

  ::std::cout << float_1 << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The best alternative would be a `floating_point_constant` counterpart of `::std::integral_constant`, but alas, it is not possible to write one.

Comment: I can not get your idea, why not just to write: 12.34f, and this would be constant of float type.

Comment: Because of possible conversions to `double`, `int` or some other type. I'd like to get the best possible approximation of source value in the destination type at compile-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's even easier than I thought:

```
int a = 1;
constexpr auto b = convert<float>(a);
```

does not compile while

```
const int a = 1;
constexpr auto b = convert<float>(a);
constexpr auto c = convert<float>(1);
constexpr auto d = convert<float>(1 + 2);
constexpr auto e = convert<int>(1.0 + 2.0);
```

does (with the obvious warnings about unused variables ;-) )

Comment: Sure, but you need a `constexpr` variable.

Comment: I'd just like to place `convert` invocations inside arbitrary expressions, without worries about run-time invocations.

Comment: i.e. you don't need a convert function for the use-case you presented at all.

Comment: @user1095108 well the convert function is yours. If you want to check if an arbitrary expression is a compile time constant, check once if it compiles with `constexpr auto foo = your_expr;` and then don't worry ever again. I don't see your problem with that.

Comment: add `static` before `constexpr`, `gdb` shows better code that way (compiler does not put the variables on the stack).